# another alternative to following approach without updating internal state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a usecase that there is a form which should be controlled one and should have its field be pre-populated so that user can edit the form. For this what i have done is

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  myInfo: makeSelectMyInfo(),
  errorResponse: makeSelectMyInfoErrorResponse()
});

const mapDispatchToPropes = dispatch => ({
  loadMyInfo: () => dispatch(getMyInfo()),
  updateMyInfo: (myInfo, token) => dispatch(updateMyInfo(myInfo, token))
});

class ConfirmPropertyByUser extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user_info: {
        contact_fname: "",
        contact_lname: "",
        agree_terms_condition: false,
      }
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadMyInfo();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.myInfo !== this.props.myInfo) {
      console.log("object", Object.values(nextProps.myInfo));
      this.setState(state => ({
        user_info: {
          ...state.user_info,
          contact_fname: nextProps.myInfo.contact_fname,
          contact_lname: nextProps.myInfo.contact_lname,
        }
      }));
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      user_info: { ...this.state.user_info, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });
  };

  handleUserTerms = e =>
    this.setState({
      user_info: {
        ...this.state.user_info,
        agree_terms_condition: e.target.checked
      }
    });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateMyInfo(this.state.user_info, this.props.match.params.id);
  };

  render() {
    const { errorResponse } = this.props;
    const { user_info } = this.state;
    let message;
    if (errorResponse && typeof errorResponse === "string") {
      message = <Notification message={errorResponse} timeout={5000} />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {message && message}
        <div className="card card-lg">
          <h1>Register</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="contact_fname"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={user_info && user_info.contact_fname}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="contact_lname"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={user_info && user_info.contact_lname}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    className="custom-control-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={this.handleUserTerms}
                  />
              </div>
              <button
                className="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg"
                disabled={
                  !user_info.password || !user_info.agree_terms_condition
                }
              >
                Submit Details
              </button>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToPropes)(
  ConfirmPropertyByUser
);
```

I am using redux and also updating the internal state. But I have heard somewhere that when using redux its unnecessary to update the internal state. How can i approach the following problem without updating the internal state? Can anyone help me on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing appears to be fine.  Per the Redux FAQ, [there's nothing wrong with using component state in a Redux app](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state).  For forms, it's very common to need to have both an "original" set of values and a "work-in-progress" copied set of values, and it's up to you whether the "WIP" values are stored in Redux or in a React component.

For what it's worth, I did show some examples of putting the "WIP" form state into Redux in my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 8: Form Draft Data Management](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-8-form-draft-data-management/), which might be a useful reference.  But, overall, your code here looks good - you're correctly copying props to state in the constructor *and* in `componentWillReceiveProps`, and the conceptual approach you're following is perfectly fine.

One small stylistic suggestion: I generally recommend that people use the object shorthand syntax for the `mapDispatch` argument.  In your case, it would look like:

```
const actions = {loadMyInfo : getMyInfo, updateMyInfo : updateMyInfo};

// later
export default connect(mapState, actions)(ConfirmPropertyByUser);
```

Comment: Some people argue that why you are updating the internal state when using redux? I asked them if its a bad pattern or some problem with re-rendering and etc but didn't get any reply.

Comment: Per the FAQ entry: it's _your_ job as a dev to decide where each piece of state should live. If it makes sense to keep the "WIP" values in the component, go ahead, that's perfectly reasonable.